# How to create executable targets that are existing targets with special build options enabled?

Tags: cmake, address-sanitizer

I have a C++ project that is built using CMake.

I am using the [`sanitizers-cmake`](https://github.com/arsenm/sanitizers-cmake) project to allow building targets with Address Sanitizer and Memory Sanitizer.  The sanitizers-cmake files define options `SANITIZE_ADDRESS`,

```
# In sanitizers-cmake/cmake/FindASan.cmake
option(SANITIZE_ADDRESS "Enable AddressSanitizer for sanitized targets." Off)

# In sanitizers-cmake/cmake/FindMSan.cmake
option(SANITIZE_MEMORY "Enable MemorySanitizer for sanitized targets." Off)
```

In my project, I have defined a library, command-line executable, and unit test suite:

```
## Library target
add_library(my_proj include/my_proj.hpp src/my_proj.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_proj PUBLIC include)
add_sanitizers(my_proj)

## Command-line executable
add_executable(my-exe my-exe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my-exe PRIVATE my_proj)

## Unit tests suite executable
add_executable(my_proj_tests tests/my_proj.t.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_proj_tests
        my_proj
        gtest_main)
add_sanitizers(my_proj_tests)
```

Is it possible to define some kind of pseudo-target named `my_proj_tests_asan` that is equivalent to `my_proj_tests` with the `SANTIZIE_ADDRESS` option enabled?  In other words, I would like to define something like:

```
add_target_copy(my_proj_tests_asan my_proj_tests)
add_target_options(my_proj_tests_asan SANITIZE_ADDRESS On)
```

Comment: Why not just create two executables, `my_proj_tests` and `my_proj_tests_asan`, but only call `add_sanitizers()` for the `my_proj_tests_asan` target? Do you have any of the sanitizers enabled? If all of your `SANITIZE_*` options are set to `OFF`, the `add_sanitizers()` call does nothing anyways (see [here](https://github.com/arsenm/sanitizers-cmake/blob/99e159ec9bc8dd362b08d18436bd40ff0648417b/cmake/FindSanitizers.cmake#L57))...

Comment: Currently, I am enabling the options with `-DSANITIZE_ADDRESS=On` at the command line.  I do not want to supply this at the command line each time.  Also, the primary thing I want to sanitize is the library target, but of course I do not want the sanitizers to be enabled for the library target in the builds of ordinary library users.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not really a functionality to "copy" an existing, configured target in CMake. It sounds like you may want to set `SANITIZE_ADDRESS` to `ON` *after* creating `my_proj_tests`, then create `my_proj_tests_asan`.